# How can I set the default value Laravel <select> element?

Tags: laravel-5.8

I want to retrieve database values in category name and i want to show default value in selection. This is my controller for my edit view.

I have a `category_product` table.

[image: category_product]

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category">category</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="category" id="category">
            @foreach($categories as $category)
                <option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ $product->categories()->category_id == $category->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

ProductController.php

```
public function edit(Product $product)
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    return view('Admin.products.edit', compact('product', 'categories'));
}
```

Product.php

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

I get this error.

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::$category_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add default value in the select tag above `foreach()` loop.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category">category</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="category" id="category">
            <option value="xyz">xyz</option> /* set default option value */
            @foreach($categories as $category)
                <option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{$category->id == $category->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want set category name selected then you need to match category in product collection. ( if you have `catetory_id` in product table )

```
 <select class="form-control" name="category" id="category">

      @foreach($categories as $category)
           <option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{$product->catetory_id == $category->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>
      @endforeach
 </select>
```

Comment: I changed my codes but my problem did not solve yet.

Comment: You just have to add the `selected`directive inside your `<option selected value="xyz"/>`tag to have that as default select. Don't forgetr to remove from the foreach option tag the selected condition then.