# How to set default value for search input for select2 bootstrap class

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, html-select

Hello Guys I'm Working On Laravel And I Want To Set Default Value for select2 Class for search input

```
 <select name="category[{{$index}}][category_id]"  class="select2 form-control"> // This Is My Select2 class and it contains search input

    <optgroup  label="Select Category">

    @if($Categories && $Categories -> count() > 0)

        @foreach($Categories as $Category)

            <option value="{{$Category-> id }}">

                {{$Category-> translation_lang}}

                {{$Category-> name}}
    
            </option>
    
        @endforeach
    @endif
    </optgroup>


        </select>
```

I Have `select2` class in my select. This Class to add search input to my select. i want to set default value to this search input how can i make  it please?????

Comment: No It doesen't has any answer please read my question again

Comment: i want to set default value for search input in select2 class

Comment: @Admin the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73420271/how-to-set-default-value-for-search-input-for-select2-bootstrap-class#:~:text=answers%20here%3A-,How%20to%20programmatically%20inject%20search%20queries%20into%20Select2%20v4%3F,-(7%20answers) has nothing to do with this question. Why was this question unanswered closed?

Comment: This is the correct duplicate with the right answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59798920/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-laravel-select-element

Answer (score 0):

Use the form helper.

```
{!!Form::select('category', isset($category) ? $category->id : null, ['id' => 'category', 'class' => 'form-control'])!!}
```

Comment: does this set default value for select2 search input